# How to return from grub prompt to the grub menu?

Tags: grub2, grub-efi

If you press escape in grub menu you end up at the grub command prompt.

My question is, how can I go back to the menu, without rebooting?

Comment: So I finally got it working using escape. I have to be very careful though to stop hitting escape at just the right time otherwise it brings me to the grub terminal and there's no way to go back to the grub startup options screen.

Comment: Is there a way to get to the Grub menu via a command? None of the below answers are working for me.

Comment: If nothing seems to work, try this: Shut down the computer/laptop
Power it up again
Press bios key to enter bios
Change the boot priority order Done! ✅

Answer (score 95):

Type `normal`, hit Enter, and then tap <kbd>Esc</kbd> until the menu is displayed. Hitting <kbd>Esc</kbd> at this point won't drop you to the grub command prompt (so don't worry about hitting <kbd>Esc</kbd> too many times).

Comment: I'm amazed the only answer to actually work for me was the one with joint least votes.

Comment: Jack, you are my hero. I searched for 2 days about this and I find it in some random answer. Your beautiful profile picture and your name will forever be engraved in my heart. Thank you, you beautiful soul.

Comment: Unfortunately, hitting escape multiple times Doesn't take you to the grub menu -- it just boots into whatever grub was going to boot into.

Answer (score 40):

Executing the `normal` command brought me back to the grub menu.

I found this command (and others) by pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> in the grub CLI.

Comment: it just boots normally, does not show the grub menu

Comment: normal does nothing on my system.

Comment: boots normaly, the answer above did the trick

Answer (score 8):

Type `exit` and then press your <kbd>Enter</kbd> key twice. Or press <kbd>Esc</kbd>.

[More info](https://web.archive.org/web/20160609133658/http://members.iinet.net:80/%7Eherman546/p20/GRUB2%20CLI%20Mode%20Commands.html)

Comment: Esc does bring me next prompt, it's like Enter and exit does exit grub and bring me back to the bootloader, rEFInd in my case. That's booted in EFI mode and maybe that's changing grub behaviour.

Comment: Umm.. weird, it should allow you to go to the boot menu according to the manuals I've found...

Comment: that starts network boot, it does not show the menu, it seems nothing does!

Comment: This just launches me into some kind of hardware testing

Comment: @BenFarmer, does the testing ever end? What happens after?

Comment: All this does is get me to `A bootable device has not been detected`.  Not useful.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Shift + Esc</kbd>: What worked for me was holding down <kbd>Shift</kbd> and pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> several times.

Comment: on virtualbox this worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Press the <kbd>q</kbd> button or type `:q`.

Answer (score 0):

for me only writing 'halt' worked